# Having trouble targeting with DOM Xpath

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I know there are many questions here about DOM traversal with XPATH. I have done a good amount of research before bringing my question here, but I am still having an issue. I'm trying to pull the number of downloads for a given app on the android market. So for instance if the app were the stack exchange app, I would want to pull the numbers: 50,000 - 100,000 from this page:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin

I am attempting to target the div with an itemprop of "numDownloads" to little avail. I have no trouble targeting other items on page I have tried (various classes, etc) but this specific item never returns results. I have checked to make sure the value is, in fact, in the source and not being inserted by JS. Here is my code:

```
        // Load up the document so we can parse the dom
    $dom = new DomDocument();
    $dom->loadHTML($this->html);

    // XPath so we can do some specific searches
    $finder = new DomXPath($dom);

    // Find all the number of downloads item on page
    $installs = $finder->query("//*[@itemprop='numDownloads']");
    echo "<pre>"; var_dump($installs); echo "</pre>";

    foreach($installs as $install) {
        echo "<pre>"; var_dump($install->nodeValue); echo "</pre>";
    }
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you are already on the right track.

```
$url = 'https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin';
$contents = file_get_contents($url);
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($contents);
$finder = new DomXPath($dom);
$installs = $finder->query("//div[@itemprop='numDownloads']");
// directly point it to a div since it is a div
foreach($installs as $install) {
    echo $install->nodeValue; // 50,000 - 100,000
}
```

Comment: Perfect, that solved it! Thank you, it's always the small things.

Comment: @carbide20 sure no prob, yeah sometimes it gets the best of us

Comment: Instead of `"//div[@itemprop='numDownloads']"` you may find that this is more efficient `"//div[@itemprop eq 'numDownloads']"`. This is because `=` is for sequence comparisons whereas `eq` is for atomic comparisons.